# WPF - XAML - Data Trigger without Binding / Value only trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have a grid of values in a DataGrid. In each cell I have one of 4 values, I want each value to have an associated colour.

In the past all my data triggers have been of the format;

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="R">
     <Setter Property="xcdg:DataRow.Background" Value="Pink" />
</DataTrigger>
```

But I need something of the format;

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding *}" Value="R">
     <Setter Property="xcdg:DataRow.Background" Value="Pink" />
</DataTrigger>
```

So that any cell's value will be checked. The reason I can't use explicit bindings is that the number of columns and their names is dynamic, I use extend CustomTypeDescriptor to expose the columns and rows to enter the grid.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" Value="Failure">
    <Setter Property="xcdg:DataRow.Background" Value="Red" />
</DataTrigger>
```

I needed to use a Relative source.

Further to that what I ended up using was;

```
        <xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources>
            <c:ColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataCell}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataRow}}}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="xcdg:DataCell.Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsDirty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataRow}}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="xcdg:DataCell.Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources>
```

Where my Colour converter looks a bit like this;

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DataCell), typeof(Brush))]
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var cell = (DataCell)value;
        var content = (string)cell.Content;

        if (content == null || cell.ParentRow.IsSelected)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        if (content == "Unknown")
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightYellow);
        }

        ...

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My only problem now is that when I scroll my background colours aren't updated when the DataRows are reused.

I can't find an event to hook into when a DataRow is reused either...

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to use a `ValueConverter` in your binding? That way you could check in the converter which value it should return.